# Why is my constructor getting a 'cannot be resolved to a type' error?

Tags: java, constructor

Assignment4.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Assignment4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int flightNum = 2399;
    String deptCity = "Phoenix";
    String arriCity = "Boston";
    double price = 473.50;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
    Flight flightOne = new Flight(flightNum, deptCity, arriCity, price);
    char choice = ' ';
    String caseD = new String("D");
    String caseA = new String("A");
    String caseI = new String("I");
    String caseR = new String("R");
    String caseS = new String("S");
    String caseM = new String("?");
    String caseQ = new String("Q");
    String letter;
    do{
    System.out.println("\tChoose an Action\n----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("D\tChange Departure City.");
    System.out.println("A\tChange Arrival City.");
    System.out.println("I\tIncrease The Price.");
    System.out.println("R\tReduce The Price.");
    System.out.println("S\tShow Flight Info.");
    System.out.println("?\tDisplay The Menu.");
    System.out.println("Q\tQuit.");
    letter = in.nextLine();
    if(letter.equals(caseD)){
        choice = 'D';
    }
     if(letter.equals(caseA)){
        choice = 'A';
     }
     if(letter.equals(caseI)){
         choice = 'I';
     }
     if(letter.equals(caseR)){
         choice = 'R';
        }
     if(letter.equals(caseS)){
         choice = 'S';
     }
     if(letter.equals(caseM)){
         choice = '?';
     }
     if(letter.equals(caseQ)){
         choice = 'Q';
     }

    // switch statement runs one of the choices based on
    // the user input, specifically the value of int choice
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'D':
            System.out.println("Enter the new departure city");
            String newDeptCity = in.nextLine();
            flightOne.setDeptCity(newDeptCity);
            System.out.println("The departure city has been changed from Phoenix to " + deptCity + ".");
        break;
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Enter the new arrival city");
            String newArriCity = in.nextLine();
            flightOne.setArriCity(newArriCity);
            System.out.println("The departure city has been changed from Boston to " + arriCity + ".");
        break;
        case 'I':
            System.out.println("Enter the increase rate (0.08):");
            double raiseRate = in.nextDouble();
            flightOne.raisePrice(raiseRate);
            System.out.println("Price was increased by " + (raiseRate * 100) + "%, the new price is " + fmt.format(price) + ".");
        break;
        case 'R':
            System.out.println("Enter the increase rate (0.05):");
            double reduceRate = in.nextDouble();
            flightOne.raisePrice(reduceRate);
            System.out.println("Price was increased by " + (reduceRate * 100) + "%, the new price is " + fmt.format(price) + ".");
        break;
        case 'S':
            flightOne.toString();
        break;
        case '?':

        break;
    }
    // exits the loop when the user enters '4'
    // (exit program) for their choice
    }while(choice != 'Q');
    in.close();
}
}
```

Flight.java

```
public class Flight {
private int flightNum = 2399;
private String deptCity = "Phoenix";
private String arriCity = "Boston";
private double price = 473.50;
public Flight(int newId, String newDepCity, String newArriCity, double newPrice){
    flightNum = newId;
    deptCity = newDepCity;
    arriCity = newArriCity;
    price = newPrice;
}
public int getFlightNum(){
    return flightNum;
}
public String getDeptCity(){
    return deptCity;
}
public String getArriCity(){
    return arriCity;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public void setFlightNum(int newFlightNum){
    flightNum = newFlightNum;
}
public void setDeptCity(String newCity){
    deptCity = newCity;
}
public void setArriCity(String newCity){
    arriCity = newCity;
}
public void raisePrice(double raiseRate){
    double newPrice = (price * raiseRate) + price;
    price = newPrice;
}
public void reducePrice(double reduceRate){
    double newPrice = price - (price * reduceRate);
    price = newPrice;
}
public String toString(){
    String result;
    result = "\nFlight No:\t" + flightNum + "\nDeparture:\t" + deptCity + "\nArrival:\t\t" + arriCity + "\nPrice:\t\t" + price + "\n\n";
    return result;
}
}
```

I'm getting an error when trying to code my constructor on line 12 of Assignment4.java:

```
Flight flightOne = new Flight(flightNum, deptCity, arriCity, price);
```

The error states "Flight cannot be resolved to a type." Why can't my Assignment4.java file find my Flight.java file? I have been googling this issue and staring at my computer for the past 3 hours and have found nothing to help me! I'm thinking it might be an issue concerning where the files are saved but I'm really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: What do you mean by import it?

Comment: Did you import your `Flight` class?

Comment: No. How do I do that?

Comment: `import package.to.Flight`

Comment: There's an error on 'package'

Comment: I didn't mean it literally... you have to replace `package.to.Flight` with your actual package name...

Comment: what IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse. do "CTRL + SHIFT + O".

Comment: On Netbeans: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `i`